# RVM not found after installing as root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I've installed RVM per the instructions at https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

I logged in as my users and then su to root. Then I followed the multi-user instructions on the install guide.

The last step it says:

> Multi-User:
>
> The rvm function will be automatically configured for every user on
>   the system if you install as root.

However, when I run the RVM command it is not found. Is there some additional step I need to do to get bash to recognize the RVM command?

Comment: have you restarted your terminal?

Comment: no, but the directions say I shouldn't have to if I am root

Comment: ok, I did source .bash_profile. But that didn't help

Comment: When RVM is installed as root it doesn't change your personal bash profiles, it updates the system-wide profiles instead. You NEED to restart your terminal for the changes.

Comment: Just log out and log back in should be enough. You should have a bunch of rvm-related stuff somewhere in the `/etc/profile*` folders that get loaded when bash loads. If all else fails you could always try and install rbenv instead: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

Comment: If it doesn't work after logging in, check that `/etc/rvmrc` exists and contains `export rvm_path="/usr/local/rvm"` line.

Comment: the file existed, but that rvm_path wasn't there. I added it and it works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the RVM webpage for the post-installation steps:

a) modify your .bash_profile , so that RVM gets started for every new shell
b) start a new shell

Note also: The author of RVM explicitly writes that he doesn't recommend installing RVM system-wide as root